# Running MVC .net 4.0 application in the same domain as an existing forms 3.5 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Our company is currently running a asp.net Webforms 3.5 website as the default website on a Server.

I would like to add a new asp.net MVC application (using .net 4.0), but be able to use Single Sign-On authentication from the forms app to the MVC app.  How can I do this?

I tried added the MVC app to the default website, but the MVC app fails since it is trying to read the web.config of the WebForms application.

I would imagine this has been done by someone out there, what is a good way to do this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CLR version is set in IIS per application pool => if you want to have two applications running two different CLR versions (2.0 and 4.0) you need to create two application pools. Once you create a second application pool you add a virtual directory and assign it to this application pool.

As for the SSO if you are using [`FormsAuthentication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) all that's necessary is to use the same `<authentication mode="Forms">` section in both applications `web.config`. In order for an authentication cookie created by the first application to be decrypted by the second same machine keys need to be used => [check out this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/aspnetsinglesignon.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Darin, I've set it up exactly as you described, but the problem seems to be with the WebForms being the default web site.  When I try to hit the MVC app, it complains about the web.config of the Webforms app.  Not sure why it is trying to validate the web.config of the WebForms app.

Comment: Try setting a physical path for the ASP.NET MVC application that is outside of the root folder for the main web site. Example: root web site - `d:\inetpub\wwwroot`, asp.net mvc root - `d:\myapp`

Comment: They are separated already c:\Projects\CPortal\CPortal (for the WebForms is the root for the default WebSite) and c:\SmartForms\SmartForms for the MVC app.

Comment: What if you create a new web site for the ASP.NET MVC application?

Comment: I tried that too Darin, but then I won't be able to use the Domain cookie Single Sign-on method that Michal talks about in the article you recommended.  Or can I still do that somehow?

Comment: You can as long as you keep the same domain (sub domain can be different). You just need to set the domain name in web.config: `<forms name=".EXAMPLE-AUTH" loginUrl="/Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" domain="example.com" />`. This will work for both `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com` and also `example.com`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Your basically trying to use a 4.0 and 3.5 app pool at the same time.  Just won't work.

I'd downgrade your MVC site to 3.5.

Comment: Thanks Jfar, I took your advice and downgraded to 3.5, there is nothing in 4.0 I am really needing right now, plus I can always upgrade later.